# Cognitive service to match an image from an image storage?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Context: We (a retailer) want to offer our customers the option to upload a picture of a product that they got from our social media accounts, to get all the details about that product (Prices, Stock, description, Variables...etc).

The cognitive service should be able to match and identify which image is this from the image storage.

My question: Do you know a way to use the cognitive services for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Vision API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) for your scenario, as it allows you to upload images and label them (on your side), train your model so that you can then evaluate and tag new images (by your users) automatically, and then you can use the images uploaded by your users to improve your classifier.